# prlimit64() linux function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, archlinux

Does anyone know what the `prlimit64()` C function does? I don't seem to have it on my x86_64 Ubuntu machine but it exists in Arch, and I can't seem to find anyone or thing who knows what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one; but it's the 64-bit version (whatever that means) of `prlimit()`; a Linux-specific function in the [`getrlimit(2)` family](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html).

It does not appear to be useful for 64-bit applications, as it relates to emulation of a 64-bit environment when one isn't available.

Comment: Thanks -- it seems obvious now!

Answer (score 5):

[`prlimit`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/prlimit.2.html) allows you to set or get rlimit resource restrictions (such as number of file handles, memory, etc.) for *another* process. It is Linux-specific.

Normally, the restrictions you can set depend on the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` macro, which is 64 on all modern systems. Therefore, the members of the structures used by `prlimit` and friends are always 64 bit wide, no matter whether you're on a 32 or 64 bit system.

However, in the obscure case that `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is 32 (which means you can't correctly work with files larger than 2GiB), you need the alternative `prlimit64` syscall to use 64 bit rlimits nonetheless.