# what is "qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369"

Tags: ubuntu, build, arm, qemu

I use gbs build(arm architecture) on my Ubuntu 12.04 and I keep getting this message:

```
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
```

This is resulting in very slow builds. Any idea what is this, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu-linaro/+bug/728630) syscall 369 is `prlimit64` (you can read more about what it does [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869229/prlimit64-linux-function)).

Comment: Not limited to Ubuntu, can likely occur anywhere qemu runs.